# Multi-threading with GUI in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a GUI for a program that is computationally intensive and takes some period of time to complete calculations. I want to display and update the processing time on the GUI, both for reference and as an indication to the user that the program is running. I've created a worker to deal with the processing time on a separate thread as follows:

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<String, String>{
    
    JLabel label;
    boolean run;
    
    public Worker(JLabel label)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.run = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //This is what's called in the .execute method
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while(run)
        {
            //This sends the results to the .process method
            publish(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime() - startTime));
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void stop()
    {
        run = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> item) {
        double seconds = Long.parseLong(item.get(item.size()-1))/1000000000.0;
        String secs = String.format("%.2f", seconds);
        //This updates the UI
        label.setText("Processing Time: " + secs + " secs");
        label.repaint();
    }
}
```

I pass a JLabel to the Worker which it displays the processing time on. The following code creates the Worker and executes a runnable that carries out the main calculations.

```
Worker worker = new Worker(jLabelProcessTime);
worker.execute();
//Check for results truncation
boolean truncate = !jCheckBoxTruncate.isSelected();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
String[] args = {fileName};
//run solution and draw graph
SpeciesSelection specSel = new SpeciesSelection(args, truncate);
Thread t = new Thread(specSel);
t.start();
t.join();
ArrayList<Double> result = specSel.getResult();
drawGraph(result);
worker.stop();
```

My problem is that the processing time does not update on the GUI until after the calculations have finished. I think I'm pretty close because without 't.join();' the timer updates fine, but the processing never completes. I'd really appreciate some help to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: A thumb-rule in Swing is to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` in order to add a GUI update task to Swing's queue, after you made your computation in a **different** thread than the GUI thread. Swing's engine will take care of thread-safely applying your update

Comment: Where are you doing `t.join();`? It looks like you're doing it on the UI thread which blocks it...

Comment: The lower part of the code is in an action performed event code block.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working as you think it is...

I created [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for you...

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingWorkerTest extends JFrame {

    public SwingWorkerTest() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("run");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("time: -");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Worker worker = new Worker(label);
                worker.execute();
                //Check for results truncation
//              boolean truncate = !jCheckBoxTruncate.isSelected();
//              long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//              String[] args = {fileName};
                //run solution and draw graph
//              SpeciesSelection specSel = new SpeciesSelection(args, truncate);
//              Thread t = new Thread(specSel);
//              t.start();
//              t.join();
//              ArrayList<Double> result = specSel.getResult();
//              drawGraph(result);
                worker.stop();

                System.out.println("button's actionPerformed finished");
            }
        });

        this.getContentPane().add(button);
        this.getContentPane().add(label);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingWorkerTest();
    }
}

class Worker extends SwingWorker<String, String>{

    JLabel label;
    boolean run;

    public Worker(JLabel label)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.run = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("doInBackground..., run=" + run);
        //This is what's called in the .execute method
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
//        while(run)
//        {
            System.out.println("running...");
            //This sends the results to the .process method
            publish(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime() - startTime));
            Thread.sleep(100);
//        }
        System.out.println("worker finished...");
        return null;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
//      System.out.println("stop");
//        run = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> item) {
        System.out.println("processed");
        double seconds = Long.parseLong(item.get(item.size()-1))/1000000000.0;
        String secs = String.format("%.2f", seconds);
        //This updates the UI
        System.out.println("updating");
        label.setText("Processing Time: " + secs + " secs");
//        label.repaint();
    }
}
```

In short I found, that `Worker.stop()` is called before `doInBackground` as a result, your run is false and so `publish` is never called.

The "fixed" code above prints (after start I resized and I clicked on run button):

```
button's actionPerformed finished
doInBackground..., run=true
running...
processed
updating
worker finished...
```

and it shows:

[image]

---

new approach with a timer

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker.StateValue;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SwingWorkerTestNew extends JFrame {

    int progress = 0;

    public SwingWorkerTestNew() {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
        JButton button = new JButton("run");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("progress: -");
        WorkerNew worker = new WorkerNew(label);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                worker.execute();
                System.out.println("button's actionPerformed finished");
            }
        });

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        this.getContentPane().add(button);
        this.getContentPane().add(label);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (worker.getState() == StateValue.STARTED) {
                    ++progress;
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
                }
                if (worker.getState() == StateValue.DONE) {
                    label.setText("done");
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingWorkerTestNew();
    }
}

class WorkerNew extends SwingWorker<String, String> {

    JLabel label;

    public WorkerNew(JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("background");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("done");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I still don't know how to resolve my problem though. Am I correct to say your intention was to show the problem rather than to offer a solution? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You stated your problem as "processing time does not update on the GUI". As you see "button's actionPerformed finished" is first message in console, so it is really running in a background. If you move your `Thred.sleep(100)` just before `publish` and it will show 0.10 secs. What is a problem you want to solve?

Comment: I would like the time displayed on the GUI to update every 100ms until the work on Thread t is complete.

Comment: In such case I'd use some daemon thread, that will be asking if your task is DONE, see [getState](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#getState--)

Answer (score 0):

I was going about this in a far too complicated manner. No SwingWorker was required. I solved it as follows:

```
//Check for results truncation
boolean truncate = !jCheckBoxTruncate.isSelected();
String[] args = {fileName};
//run solution and draw graph
SpeciesSelection specSel = new SpeciesSelection(args, truncate);
Thread t = new Thread(specSel);
t.start();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

new Thread()
{
   public void run() {
   while(!specSel.isFinished())
   {
    double seconds = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000000.0;
    String secs = String.format("%.2f", seconds);
    jLabelProcessTime.setText("Processing Time: " + secs + " secs");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SpecSelGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }
ArrayList<Double> result = specSel.getResult();
    drawGraph(result);
   }
}.start();
```

Comment: It would be more correct to replace `jLabelProcessTime.setText("Processing Time: " + secs + " secs");` with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable { public void run() { jLabelProcessTime.setText("Processing Time: " + secs + " secs"); } } );`